# Xero Api Custom Tags

Tags: xero-api

I am working on a dashboard that integrates with the Xero API. I'm using xero-node and the documentation is great, highly recommended. However, as a more general Xero API question, what are good patterns for handling custom information on Employees and Invoices.

The goal is to tag Employees or Invoices so that they can be selected to be included in the dashboard. The tag is not dependent on any existing field in the Xero API. If users could tag employees/invoices in the Xero dashboard, that'd be even cooler (but not possible AFAIK).

How to input, store and retrieve custom associated info information in Xero?  Mapping to objects in our own database would work, but the actual 'tagging' of entities seems to require another view.

https://central.xero.com/s/question/0D53m00006DGEB2CAP/can-i-create-my-own-custom-fields-yet

```
Many businesses just use a workaround where they set up an item in "Products and Services" with the list of custom information they need to include with their invoices
```

I feel like there should be a more elegant pattern to solve this for Employees and Invoices, that is user friendly to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using tracking categories?
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/trackingcategories